# matlab coordinates

Tags: matlab, 3d, coordinates, mesh

Im working with a small project involving plotting some coordinates in Matlab.

Below is a sample of my csv file. Total lines of data are approx 160,000:

> 31040,55725,0 
>   30930,55725,-1 
>   30875,55630,3 
>   30765,55630,0 
>   30655,55630,5 
>   30545,55630,0

The two first columns are the x,y coordinates, and the third one is the value of them.
The data is generated from a rpg kind of game. Where the player do something at a given coordinate and then he either finds something (0 < z <= 23 ) or nothing (z = 0). (z = -1 means not sure, can be ignored in this case). Sine the player can play the game over and over again, some of the x,y coordinates will have the same or different values.

So what I want to do is make a 3D plot that shows how many times a coordinate has had a hit, and what the values of the hits were, somewhat like a histogram?

My values ranges from x: 30000 - 33000, Y: 55000 - 56000 and z: -1 - 23.

I tried to use the mesh/meshgrid on a sample file containing 5 rows and it worked. But the x,y,z coordinates were always wrongly placed even though I tried to rearrange the columns or transpose the matrices.

Note: When I tried the code with my original file, i got "Out of memory" error. Can't Matlab take a lot of data? Or is it my code?

The simple code that I tried is shown below:

```
x = test(:, 1);
y = test(:, 2);
z = test(:, 3);

zz = [x,y,z];
%R = meshgrid(zz);
%mesh(R);
mesh(zz)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with custom function:

```
sel = test(:,3) > 0; % work only with z>0
x = test(sel,1) - min(test(sel,1)) + 1; % convert from x to legitimate indices
y = test(sel,2) - min(test(sel,2)) + 1;
a = accumarray( {x, y}, test(sel,3), [max(x) max(y)], @numel, [], true );
% plot using bar3
bar3( a, 1, 'detached' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(30000:33000,55000:56000);
Z=zeros(size(X));
Z(31040-30000+1,55725-55000+1) = 0;
Z(31930-30000+1,55725-55000+1) = -1;
Z(30875-30000+1,55630-55000+1) = 3;
mesh(Z)
```

Note that:
- size(X) == size(Y)

> > So what I want to do is make a 3D plot that shows how many times a coordinate has had a hit, and what the values of the hits were, somewhat like a histogram?

You could increment the appropriate Z(i,j) field to count the frequency of the coordinate appearance.

Comment: This is how I was thinking it should be like, but you're not expecting me to plot 160,000 lines of Z(x,y) = value; in my code file? I'm thinking of a way like in @Shai answer. Anyhow there seems to be two problems with this code. While it seemingly seems to work, the values I'm reading from the figure aren't 100% correct? Also I would like, if possible to have the real coordinates for each z value. That will make it easier to read from the figure for me, but not a necessity. Thanks for quick answer to both you and Shai